# Incomes of different professions

Tags: labor-economics

Doctors average salary is around \$110,000 a year, whereas NBA stars salary may well cross \$5,000,000 a season.

Why do sports players and television stars make more than doctors and politicians?

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10742/why-do-celebrities-get-high-wages

Answer (score 0):

NBA stars create more money (ticket prices, jersey sales, merchandising, branding). However, only few basketball players play in the NBA, the 99% of basketball players are amateurs. But all the doctors earn realitively well.